# Symmetric triangles with text and reflexion

Tags: tikz-pgf

**My question**

A more elegant solution to draw the images below?

With text
[image: ![enter image description here]

with very short maths
[image]

or optional arrows 
[image]

I need to reuse multiple times that type of graph to show the symmetry/opposition between different concepts (hence the `\newcommand` to wrap the `tikzfigure` to use it with parameters)

My solution is far too manual.

**What I'd need**

1. a less manual solution to draw the triangles in opposition.
2. Text (or maths) to fit more harmoniously in the triangle
3. to be able to mirror the figure horizontally

`MWE`

```
    \documentclass[border =2mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
     \usetikzlibrary{shapes}

    \newcommand{\Balance}[3]
    {
    \def\Leftlbl{#1}
     \def\Rightlbl{#2}
     \def\Centerlbl{#3}

    \coordinate (A) at (0,0.05);
    \coordinate (B) at (-0.4,-1);
    \coordinate (C) at (0.4,-1);
    \coordinate (D) at (-5,0);
    \coordinate (E) at (-5,-1.5);
    \coordinate (F) at (5,0);
    \coordinate (G) at (5,1.5);

    \fill[orange!70] (A) -- (B) -- (C);
    \draw [draw=orange!50,fill=orange!50, text opacity=1] (D)--(E)--(0,0)--cycle;
    \draw [draw=orange!80,fill=orange!80, text opacity=1] (F)--(G)--(0,0)--cycle;
    \node[color=white]  at (barycentric cs:A=1,B=1,C=1) {\small{\Centerlbl}};
    \node[color=red]  at (-4.2,-0.6) {\tiny{\Leftlbl}};
    \node[color=blue]  at (4.2,0.6) {\tiny{\Rightlbl}};
    \node[circle,fill=red,opacity=0.5]  at (0,0) {};                    
    }

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \Balance{text or math that can be lon or short}{but needs fitting}{1 word}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `eqparbox` to make the left and right nodes equally wide. Then the triangle can be computed from the intersection between a line that goes through the origin and the bottom right (top left) corner of the left (right) node and a vertical line at the left (right) boundary of this node. In order to use `eqparbox`, you need to give the pictures a unique `id`. It is then sufficient to say

```
 \pic{balance={d=2cm,
    L={$\theta$},
    left node/.append style={font=\Huge},
    left={fill=cyan!60},
    R={$\Gamma^+$},
    right node/.append style={font=\Huge},
    right={fill=magenta!60},
    B={$\Delta^0$},
    bottom node/.append style={font=\small},
    bottom={fill=orange!80},id=B
    }};
```

to obtain

[image]

The triangles adjust their sizes to the texts

[image]

The parameters `d` and `r` are explained through this picture.

[image]

This is the code with examples.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{pics/balance/.style={code={
    \tikzset{balance/.cd,#1}%
    \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/balance/##1}}% 
    \path (0,0) coordinate (O)
      (-\pv{d},0) 
        node[below left,balance/left node] (L) {\eqmakebox[\pv{id}][l]{\pv{L}}}
      (\pv{d},0) node[above right,balance/right node]  
      (R) {\eqmakebox[\pv{id}][r]{\pv{R}}}
      (0,-\pv{v}) node[below=\pv{v},balance/bottom node] (B){\pv{B}}
      let \p1=($(L.north)-(L.south)$),\p2=($(R.north)-(R.south)$),
        \n1={max(\y1,\y2)} in 
      (-\pv{d},-\n1)  coordinate (Laux)
      (\pv{d},\n1) coordinate (Raux)
      ;
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
     \path[balance/left side] 
        (O) -|
      (intersection of O--Laux and L.south west--L.north west) coordinate (BL)
      -- cycle; 
     \path[balance/right side] (O) -|
      (intersection of O--Raux and R.south east--R.north east) coordinate (TR)
        -- cycle; 
    \path[balance/bottom side] (O) -- 
     (intersection of O--B.north east and B.south west--B.south east)
      -- 
      (intersection of O--B.north west and B.south west--B.south east)
      -- cycle;    
    \end{scope}       
    \path[balance/left arrow style] (BL|-O) -- (BL);
    \path[balance/right arrow style]    (TR|-O) -- (TR);
    \path (O) node[balance/c]{}; 
    }},balance/.cd,L/.initial={A},R/.initial={A},B/.initial={$=$},
    left side/.style={fill=orange},
    left/.code={\tikzset{balance/left side/.style={#1}}},
    right side/.style={fill=orange},
    right/.code={\tikzset{balance/right side/.style={#1}}},
    bottom side/.style={fill=orange},
    bottom/.code={\tikzset{balance/bottom side/.style={#1}}},
    left arrow style/.style={},
    left arrow/.code={\tikzset{balance/left arrow style/.style={#1}}},
    right arrow style/.style={},
    right arrow/.code={\tikzset{balance/right arrow style/.style={#1}}},
    left node/.style={text=red},
    right node/.style={text=blue},
    bottom node/.style={text=white},
    c/.style={circle,inner sep=0.5ex,fill=red,opacity=0.8},
    d/.initial=1cm,v/.initial=2em,r/.initial=0.5ex,
    id/.initial=A}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \pic{balance={L={text or math that can be long or short},
    left node/.append style={font=\tiny},
    left={fill=orange!60},
    R={but needs fitting},
    right node/.append style={font=\tiny},
    B={WOI},
    bottom node/.append style={font=\small},
    bottom={fill=orange!80},id=A
    }};
\end{tikzpicture}   
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \pic{balance={d=2cm,
    L={$\theta$},
    left node/.append style={font=\Huge},
    left={fill=cyan!60},
    R={$\Gamma^+$},
    right node/.append style={font=\Huge},
    right={fill=magenta!60},
    B={$\Delta^0$},
    bottom node/.append style={font=\small},
    bottom={fill=orange!80},id=B
    }};
\end{tikzpicture}   
\begin{tikzpicture} 
 \pic{balance={d=3cm,
    L={loss on cash},
    left={draw=brown,fill=red!20},
    left arrow={draw=red,-stealth,thick},
    R={gain in future},
    right={draw=brown,fill=blue!20},
    right arrow={draw=blue,-stealth,thick},
    B={$=$},
    bottom={fill=orange!80},id=C
    }}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path  pic (docu) {balance={d=2cm,r=1em,
    L={$\theta$},
    left node/.append style={font=\Huge},
    left={fill=cyan!60},
    R={$\Gamma^+$},
    right node/.append style={font=\Huge},
    right={fill=magenta!60},
    B={$\Delta^0$},
    bottom={fill=orange!80},id=D
    }};
    \draw [|<->|,>=latex] (0,0) -- node[below]{$d$} (2,0);
    \draw [|<->|,>=latex] (docuR.south east|-0,0) -- node[below]{$r$} ++ (-1em,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```